# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined(type)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, strapi

I have a project built on NextJs for the frontend and strapi cms for the backend. I have a collection type called blogs to publish blogs on my website. I have added the blog with all the necessary fields but the blog shows: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined type`. There is no problem with the API as I am getting the complete object for that blog. For some reason, it is not fetching the blog. I have added many blogs earlier and those blogs are working but now when I am trying to add a new blog I am getting this error and then after like 30 minutes I am getting a 404 page.

Here is the `blogs/[slug].js` file:

```jsx
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { fetchAPI, updateViews } from "../../utils/api";
import InsightsSinglePageLayout from "@/components/elements/insights-single-layout";

const Blog = ({ blog, similarBlogs }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the views count
    fetchAPI(`/blogs?slug=${blog.slug}`)
      .then((latestBlog) => {
          updateViews("blogs", latestBlog[0]);
      });

  }, []);

  return (
    <section>
        <InsightsSinglePageLayout insightsData = {blog}
                                  similarInsight = {similarBlogs}
                                  type={blog.type.title.toLowerCase()}/>
    </section>
  ) 
};

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const blog = await fetchAPI(`/blogs?slug=${context.params.slug}`)
  const similarBlogs = await fetchAPI(`/solutions?title=${blog[0].solution?.title}`)

  return {
    props: {
      blog : blog[0],
      similarBlogs : similarBlogs[0] ? similarBlogs[0].blogs.filter(data => data.id != blog[0].id).slice(0,5) : [] ,
    },
  };
};
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const blogs = await fetchAPI('/blogs')
  const slugs = blogs.map(blog => blog.slug)
  const paths = slugs.map(slug => ( {params : { slug : slug.toString() }} ))
  return{
      paths,
      fallback:false
  }
};
export default Blog;
```

I have restarted the staging server hoping to get a better error and try to debug it but I am getting the same error.

Comment: Your question is really not focused at some specific problem. We cannot predict how your answer from API looks like now. But I can assume the problem is at type={blog.type.title.toLowerCase() . Can try to console.log(blog) so you can abe sure the "type" exists and also has a title?

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your responses. I have got the solution for it. This issue was causing because of getStaticProps.

The number of blogs in my backend crossed 100 blogs and getstaticprops was not able to fetch the recent blogs for me.

For it to work I had to simply make fallback = true, though this is not a correct solution for it as it will cause some performance issues, I will have to write my query in such a way that it fetches the blogs in descending order, so I will get my recent blogs without any error.